# Convert HTML to PDF using XMLWorker library doesn't work

Tags: android, pdf, itext, xmlworker

I have an `HTML` document which I need to convert to PDF format. I have added iText `XMLWorker` library to my project and wrote this snippet:

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("testing.pdf"));
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(docString.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
document.close();
file.close();
```

But the problem is that I can't include neither `Document` nor `PdfWriter`. They are not included in the library and when I tried to add

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

no `.text` is found in the library added.

What is the problem? Is there any thing missing? Should I include something else?

Comment: XML Worker is an add-on for iText. You have the XML Worker library, but not the iText library. And while we are at it: why are you using the old iText 5 + the old XML Worker, when it has been replaced with iText 7 and pdfHTML? See http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml

Comment: I have included iText 7.0 to my app but HtmlConverter can't be imported, although I have added all sub-libraries to the project !!

Comment: I'm pretty sure some sublibraries are missing. Show us your POM.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie OP does not use Maven (or Gradle, because Android), because if they were, then adding a dependency on XMLWorker would automatically pull in the required dependency. Therefore I conclude that they can not and will not show you their POM.

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 to use in android iText7 and pdfHtml works fine using this in your build.gradle

implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.5'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:html2pdf:2.1.2'

This the latest release.